# Can an if statement be placed in another if else statment?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I feel like I should be able to find this from a google search, but have not, so I'll ask it here.

I keep getting an error on the second if statement, so I was wondering if it was not allowed to place another if statement inside a pre-existing if/else statement.

Thanks for looking.

```
function flipImages(){
    currentImage = flipArray[i];

    if (i == 6) {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
    else {
        // add an opacity animation to the flip so that it is less jarring 
        // set at a 100ms fade in

        $(currentImage).animate({
            opacity: 1 
        }, 100, function() {
            console.log(flipArray[i]);
        }

        // also animate in the child divs of the currentImage (which will only be text on 
        // the "final" div) 
        if ( $(currentImage).children().hasClass('final'){
            $(currentImage).children().animate({
                opacity: 1,
                left: '+=50'
            }, 500, function(){
                console.log( $(currentImage).children() );
            });
        });
    );
    i++;
    };              
}
```

Comment: You have a missing ) after hasClass('final'). Should be hasClass('final'))

Comment: It is allowed, you just have a syntax error. You're missing a `)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U've missed a ) after `if ($(currentImage).children().hasClass('final')` and also couple of semicolons that makesit an invalid js.

```
function flipImages() {
    currentImage = flipArray[i];

    if (i == 6) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        // add an opacity animation to the flip so that it is less jarring 
        // set at a 100ms fade in

        $(currentImage).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 100, function () {
            console.log(flipArray[i]);
        });

        // also animate in the child divs of the currentImage (which will only be text on 
        // the "final" div) 
        if ($(currentImage).children().hasClass('final')) {
            $(currentImage).children().animate({
                opacity: 1,
                left: '+=50'
            }, 500, function () {
                console.log($(currentImage).children());
            });
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

**[Check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/jubair/DX7Aa/)**

Answer (score 1):

You're missing several closing brackets and braces, or have some in the wrong places. Using a decent editor with syntax highlighting makes it easy to spot errors like this.

For the record, yes it is possible to nest `if` statements - assuming your syntax is sound.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
function flipImages(){
    currentImage = flipArray[i];

    if (i == 6) {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
    else {
        // add an opacity animation to the flip so that it is less jarring 
        // set at a 100ms fade in

        $(currentImage).animate({
            opacity: 1 
        }, 100, function() {
            console.log(flipArray[i]);
        });

        // also animate in the child divs of the currentImage (which will only be text on 
        // the "final" div) 
        if ($(currentImage).children().hasClass('final')) {
            $(currentImage).children().animate({
                opacity: 1,
                left: '+=50'
            }, 500, function(){
                console.log( $(currentImage).children() );
            });
        };
        i++;
    };              
}
```